# ace:selectMenu and unwanted blank value

Tags: icefaces

I have an `ace:selectMenu` nested with a `<f:selectItems value="#{formLayout.formSelectList}" />` and formSelectList which has two elements (SelectItem objects), but I'm still with a blank element at top in my select input.

How can I make this work?

My full code:

```
  <ace:selectMenu valueChangeListener="#{formLayout.onFormChange}" disabled="#{formLayout.editMode}" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{formLayout.formSelectList}" /> 
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Integer"/> 
    <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
</ace:selectMenu>
```

I'm using icefaces 4.1.1

Comment: Do you want the select menu to display the current value? If so, then do something like this: `<ace:selectMenu ... value="#{formLayout.currentValue}">`